# ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError if model inside form is updated

Tags: angular

I know how change detection mechanism works in Angular, but this example had me stumped. There is a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/qREV8CaJHxedSmkLHZ6F?p=preview).

if you push any key while input is active an error occurs:

- if you remove `form` tag it will work
- if you initiate an event outside `template` tag (e.g. create an `input` tag next to `template` tag in `table-view` ) it will work
- if you remove `[(ngModel)]="item.model"` form `my-app` template it will work
- if you remove `selectedItem === item` from `table-view` template it will work
- if you replace `this.selectedItem = item` with `this.selectedItem = this.items[0]` it will work

So what can I guess, `selectedItem` cannot be updated with **new** object through `ngModel` when `form` tag exists or event was originated from `template` tag content. Probably after event occurs, detection mechanism runs and after `ngModel+form` update `selectedItem` again.

Any idea why does error occur? How to fix it without steps above?

Comment: `cdRef.detectChanges` should help you. When you change `selectedItem` `blur` event is firing and `form` gets another status

Comment: This is because of the `AfterContentInit`. Angular checks the template after it has been initialized, and values has been changed. I believe `AfterContentInit()` and other events such as `AfterViewInit()` are there to check specific contents, but not actually manipulating data.

Try using other events such as `OnInit()` and manipulate your data after everything was done correctly.

Comment: @yurzui, you are right! That's due to blur... but why angular doesn't run change detection in that case?

Comment: The article [Everything you need to know about the `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` error](https://medium.com/@maximus.koretskyi/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-error-e3fd9ce7dbb4) explains this behavior in great details